# Глобальная переменная в проекте - как реализовать?

Tags: python, django

В Django-проекте необходимо реализовать доступ в методах моделей к информации, вычисляемой через `request`. Информацию нужно вычислить один раз (несколько параметров), и как-то хранить и передавать.

Как это сделать правильно? С помощью Signleton'а, если правильно понимаю, получится непотокобезопасное решение.

Comment: Не будет ли логичнее хранить эту информацию в БД? Добавьте конкретики, что это за информация?

Comment: Синглтон вполне можно сделать потокобезопасным, но всё равно не надо такую гадость делать.

Comment: Здесь действительно необходимо что-то вроде глобальной переменной. Проект (интернет-магазин) реализует сайт с системой региональных поддоменов (spb.site.ru, kazan.site.ru и др - поддоменов может быть много, поэтому SITE_ID в settings вынести не получится). Есть различные параметры, задаваемые в админке - например, поправочный коэффициент к ценам (привязан к поддомену). Гораздо яснее кажется сделать middleware для вычисления нужных параметров (зависят от request'а) и сделать @property price() в моделях (задавая base_price), чем переписывать половину логики (оформление заказа/корзина/темплейты).

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы вам не использовать переменную окружения:

```
import os
os.environ['GLOBAL_VARIABLES'] = {'var1': 1, 'var2': 2}
```

Кстати, для запуска django-проекта через wsgi как раз используется этот приём (чтобы как-то сослаться на настройки проекта для всех запущенных экземпляров python).

Answer (score 0):

Сколько я не пытался найти информацию о глобальных переменных в django, везде говорят, что не желательно их использовать. Если хотите использовать их, то она вызывается также как и в python. А почему бы вам не попробовать такое решение  [вашей проблемы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)?

Comment: Не совсем понял: к чему ссылка на urlconf?

Comment: По факту, в Django есть SITE_ID, который задается в setting'ах. Но у меня он определяется динамически, и от него зависит очень многое. Передавать request во все методы модели - это гораздо хуже, чем глобальная переменная, на мой взгляд.